# Best level grind for a Hunter from 34-45?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

So, last night was the fourth night strike out of getting people to group up for a Garth Agarwen runs. I am told players don't like that zone. So...

As a rather new player to LOTRO, where can a Hunter go to gain xp quickly if grouping is not an option? Keeping in mind I loathe the fetch quests in the game, they take forever.

Comment: You do know that the rewards for GA are quite nice? lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Item:Eglain_Token

Answer (score 5):

Skirmish. That's my preferred way of leveling, especially with the daily quests for them.

Comment: +1 for Skirmishes. They are hands down the fastest way to level in LotRO.

Comment: And remarkably fun, IMHO, especially if you can find a friend to run them with.

Comment: You also get more XP if you have a larger group (more enemies = more XP)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you, quests do drag the game out forever, however don't pass up on the Epic Book quests, if done a couple levels below the recommendations, you will get a lot of XP. and I agree Trevel that Skirms are the best way to gain XP as well. Personally from L20 to L45 all I do are Epic Book quests and Skirms!

Answer (score 0):

What I di was head out and killed Wargs and Goblins in the Angmar region. You can also make up to 7 gold in an hour.